# Bash script to to split list based upon whether row item exists in secondary list?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have two lists of values that need to be processed, IDlist1 and IDlist2. The action I'm trying to perform is to loop through IDlist1 and check whether each row entry exists within IDList2 and then separate the values based upon whether they match or not. Is there a specific operator or script that can help accomplish this as gracefully as possible?

| Example IDlist1 |
| --- |
| TZ001 |
| TZ002 |
| TZ004 |
| TZ006 |
| TZ007 |
| TZ009 |
| TZ011 |

| IDlist2 |
| --- |
| TZ001 |
| TZ004 |
| TZ006 |
| TZ007 |

| Output1 (IDlist1 exists in IDlist2) |
| --- |
| TZ001 |
| TZ004 |
| TZ006 |
| TZ007 |

| Output2 (IDlist1 that does not match/exist in IDlist2) |
| --- |
| TZ002 |
| TZ009 |
| TZ011 |

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux SE. Please [edit] and add example input and the desired output. What is your research effort? "Gimme a script" is not a good attitude. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for `comm` of `grep -f`, but without an example input and desired output, we can't really know.

Comment: Updated the post with example inputs and expected output values, apologies!

Comment: Few questions. Positive answers to these may lead to simpler methods or methods requiring less resources. (1) Your example input lists are sorted. May we assume it's always so? (2) In your example every line from `IDlist2` appears in `IDlist1`. May we assume it's always so? (3) In your example the lines in `IDlist1` are unique. May we assume it's always so? (4) In your example the lines in `IDlist2` are unique. May we assume it's always so? (5) You wrote "match/exist". Should we assume fixed strings, not patterns (like in `grep -F`)?

Comment: Thank you for the followup! (1)IDs may appear unsorted and with various alpha-numeric configurations. (2) There may instances where items appear in IDList2 and not IDlist1. (3) Yes, IDList1 ought to always be unique. (4) Yes, IDlist2 ought to always be unique. (5) I'm not sure I follow here, each new line should designate a separate string to match between the ID lists. Thank you!

Comment: Variations of your question have been asked dozens, if not hundreds of times on U&L.  e.g. search for something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=rows+in+file1+and+file2 - the solutions usually involve `grep -f file2 file1`, awk, or perl (with the last two, usually something like: read file2 into a hash, then read file1 and compare...i.e. pretty much the same as `grep -f`).  Your question could/should be closed as a dupe, but I just don't have time to search for the closest match.  That can be something for you to do.

Answer (score 1):

An Awk solution:

Awk script file `checklists.awk`:

```c
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

NR == FNR {
    # Recording first input script file (for you, IDList2)
    hash[$1] = $0
    next
}
$1 in hash {
    # if second file key is found in first file 
    print hash[$1]
    next
}
{
    # if second file key is not found in first file 
    print $1 > OUTPUT_FILENAME_NOT_FOUND
}
```

Change script execution modes:

```bash
chmod 755 checklists.awk
```

Awk script executed like that:

```bash
./checklists.awk -v OUTPUT_FILENAME_NOT_FOUND="./Output2"  IDlist2 IDlist1 > ./Output1
```

Warning, "IDlist2" file (the reference), is the first data file for Awk script.

Answer (score 1):

Appears the standard `join` command meets your requirement.

### Output1 (IDlist1 exists in IDlist2)

```
$ join idlist1 idlist2
TZ001
TZ004
TZ006
TZ007
$
```

### Output2 (IDlist1 that does not match/exist in IDlist2)

```
$ join -v 1 idlist1 idlist2
TZ002
TZ009
TZ011
$
```